# number_format on 1 million return Nan0

Tags: php, laravel

i try to convert number with number format on laravel this code

```
<span class="count-text" data-speed="3000" data-stop="{{ number_format(1164116,0,) }}">0</span>
```

but output is nan0 . the result on image below

[image]

Comment: NaN stands for 'Not a Number'. You can check a numeric value by using is_nan(...), see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php.

Comment: the code :
<span class="count-text" data-speed="3000" data-stop="{{ number_format(1164116,0, ',' , '.') }}">0</span>

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add the relevant code. Your post gives no information. `NaN` is usually returned by javascript, not PHP. Your number_format is returning `"1.164.116"`, which is not usually a valid number format for programming languages.

Comment: `number_format()` converts a number into a human readable string. The result will no longer be a valid number that JS  (or PHP) can use.

Comment: thanks for suggest.  i re-chech again my code . i found some issue on jquery countdown not on number format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `number_format` PHP code works fine, however you don't want this formatted. You want to provide the plain, raw number as the `data-stop` attribute.

```
data-stop="1164116"
```